# Qt Sqlite only creates one table from script

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

I have the following script that I am using in a QString in qt and supplying to a QSqlQuery to create tables in a Sqlite database.

The Script.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts
(
   A_Id           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   Account_Name   TEXT,
   Account_Date   TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE statements
(
   S_Id           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   Statement_Name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE transactions
(
   T_Id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   A_Id              INTEGER,
   S_Id              INTEGER,
   Amount            REAL,
   Transaction_Date  TEXT,
   FOREIGN KEY(A_Id) REFERENCES accounts(A_Id),
   FOREIGN KEY(S_Id) REFERENCES statements(S_Id)
);
```

However when the scripts runs only the first table gets created in the database.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not familiar with qt, but it seems likely that `QSqlQuery` can only process one SQLite statement at a time. Break up your SQL into three separate calls to `QSqlQuery::exec`, one for each table.

Answer (score 3):

QSqlQuery forwards the statement to the SQlite driver where the query-strings is analysed by sqlite3_prepare(...). The [documentation](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) says that "These routines only compile the first statement in zSql". Conclusion: This is a "feature" of SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help you:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("your_nameDB.db");
QSqlQuery query(db);
query.exec("CREATE TABLE Accounts"
           "(A_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Account_Name TEXT,Account_Date TEXT)");
```